# ¿Còmo puedo mostrar una tabla de conversión de grados fahrenheit a celsius?

Tags: java

Tengo este código pero  no me da el resultado esperado si no que, en la columna de centigrados me da 1.00 en vez de la conversión

```
  package grados;

  public class Grados {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] gradosf= new int[65];
    double [] gradosc= new double[65];
    double conversion=0;
    System.out.printf("Grados Fahrenheit\t  Grados Centigrados\n");

    for(int i=0; i<=gradosf.length; i++){
        gradosf [i]=i+1;
        conversion=(gradosf [5/9*(i-32)] );

      System.out.printf("%d    \t    %.2f\n", gradosf[i], conversion );     

      }
    }
  }
```

y me da esto

```
  Grados Fahrenheit   Grados Centigrados
    1                               1,00
    2                               1,00
    3                               1,00
    4                               1,00
    5                               1,00
    6                               1,00
    7                               1,00
    8                               1,00
    9                               1,00
    10                              1,00
    11                              1,00
     .                                .  
     .                                .                                  
    65                              1,00

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65
  at grados.Grados.main(Grados.java:11)
  C:\Users\Caja\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor- 
  snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
  BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

pero necesito que me de la conversion de grados fahrenheit a celsius

Comment: gradosf es un arreglo, por qué tienes en el indice una formula ? gradosf [5/9*(i-32)], busca cómo se asignan valores a los arreglos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para arreglar el java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65
debes de hacer:

```
for(int i=0; i<gradosf.length; i++){
```

la formula para la conversión es esta:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            double conversion = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                conversion = ((i*1.8)+32);

                System.out.println("Grados Centigrados: "+i+ " Grados Fahrenheit : "+conversion);
                // Conversion al reves
                //conversion = (i-32)/1.8;
                //System.out.println("Grados Fahrenheit: "+i+ " Grados Centigrados: "+conversion);

            }

    }
```

El resultado seria este:

```
Grados Centigrados: 0 Grados Fahrenheit: 32.0
Grados Centigrados: 1 Grados Fahrenheit: 33.8
Grados Centigrados: 2 Grados Fahrenheit: 35.6
Grados Centigrados: 3 Grados Fahrenheit: 37.4
Grados Centigrados: 4 Grados Fahrenheit: 39.2
Grados Centigrados: 5 Grados Fahrenheit: 41.0
Grados Centigrados: 6 Grados Fahrenheit: 42.8
Grados Centigrados: 7 Grados Fahrenheit: 44.6
Grados Centigrados: 8 Grados Fahrenheit: 46.4
Grados Centigrados: 9 Grados Fahrenheit: 48.2
Grados Centigrados: 10 Grados Fahrenheit: 50.0
Grados Centigrados: 11 Grados Fahrenheit: 51.8
Grados Centigrados: 12 Grados Fahrenheit: 53.6
Grados Centigrados: 13 Grados Fahrenheit: 55.400000000000006
Grados Centigrados: 14 Grados Fahrenheit: 57.2
Grados Centigrados: 15 Grados Fahrenheit: 59.0
Grados Centigrados: 16 Grados Fahrenheit: 60.8
Grados Centigrados: 17 Grados Fahrenheit: 62.6
Grados Centigrados: 18 Grados Fahrenheit: 64.4
Grados Centigrados: 19 Grados Fahrenheit: 66.2
Grados Centigrados: 20 Grados Fahrenheit: 68.0
Grados Centigrados: 21 Grados Fahrenheit: 69.80000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 22 Grados Fahrenheit: 71.6
Grados Centigrados: 23 Grados Fahrenheit: 73.4
Grados Centigrados: 24 Grados Fahrenheit: 75.2
Grados Centigrados: 25 Grados Fahrenheit: 77.0
Grados Centigrados: 26 Grados Fahrenheit: 78.80000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 27 Grados Fahrenheit: 80.6
Grados Centigrados: 28 Grados Fahrenheit: 82.4
Grados Centigrados: 29 Grados Fahrenheit: 84.2
Grados Centigrados: 30 Grados Fahrenheit: 86.0
Grados Centigrados: 31 Grados Fahrenheit: 87.80000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 32 Grados Fahrenheit: 89.6
Grados Centigrados: 33 Grados Fahrenheit: 91.4
Grados Centigrados: 34 Grados Fahrenheit: 93.2
Grados Centigrados: 35 Grados Fahrenheit: 95.0
Grados Centigrados: 36 Grados Fahrenheit: 96.8
Grados Centigrados: 37 Grados Fahrenheit: 98.60000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 38 Grados Fahrenheit: 100.4
Grados Centigrados: 39 Grados Fahrenheit: 102.2
Grados Centigrados: 40 Grados Fahrenheit: 104.0
Grados Centigrados: 41 Grados Fahrenheit: 105.8
Grados Centigrados: 42 Grados Fahrenheit: 107.60000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 43 Grados Fahrenheit: 109.4
Grados Centigrados: 44 Grados Fahrenheit: 111.2
Grados Centigrados: 45 Grados Fahrenheit: 113.0
Grados Centigrados: 46 Grados Fahrenheit: 114.8
Grados Centigrados: 47 Grados Fahrenheit: 116.60000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 48 Grados Fahrenheit: 118.4
Grados Centigrados: 49 Grados Fahrenheit: 120.2
Grados Centigrados: 50 Grados Fahrenheit: 122.0
Grados Centigrados: 51 Grados Fahrenheit: 123.8
Grados Centigrados: 52 Grados Fahrenheit: 125.60000000000001
Grados Centigrados: 53 Grados Fahrenheit: 127.4
Grados Centigrados: 54 Grados Fahrenheit: 129.2
Grados Centigrados: 55 Grados Fahrenheit: 131.0
Grados Centigrados: 56 Grados Fahrenheit: 132.8
Grados Centigrados: 57 Grados Fahrenheit: 134.60000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 58 Grados Fahrenheit: 136.4
Grados Centigrados: 59 Grados Fahrenheit: 138.2
Grados Centigrados: 60 Grados Fahrenheit: 140.0
Grados Centigrados: 61 Grados Fahrenheit: 141.8
Grados Centigrados: 62 Grados Fahrenheit: 143.60000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 63 Grados Fahrenheit: 145.4
Grados Centigrados: 64 Grados Fahrenheit: 147.2
Grados Centigrados: 65 Grados Fahrenheit: 149.0
Grados Centigrados: 66 Grados Fahrenheit: 150.8
Grados Centigrados: 67 Grados Fahrenheit: 152.60000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 68 Grados Fahrenheit: 154.4
Grados Centigrados: 69 Grados Fahrenheit: 156.2
Grados Centigrados: 70 Grados Fahrenheit: 158.0
Grados Centigrados: 71 Grados Fahrenheit: 159.8
Grados Centigrados: 72 Grados Fahrenheit: 161.6
Grados Centigrados: 73 Grados Fahrenheit: 163.4
Grados Centigrados: 74 Grados Fahrenheit: 165.20000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 75 Grados Fahrenheit: 167.0
Grados Centigrados: 76 Grados Fahrenheit: 168.8
Grados Centigrados: 77 Grados Fahrenheit: 170.6
Grados Centigrados: 78 Grados Fahrenheit: 172.4
Grados Centigrados: 79 Grados Fahrenheit: 174.20000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 80 Grados Fahrenheit: 176.0
Grados Centigrados: 81 Grados Fahrenheit: 177.8
Grados Centigrados: 82 Grados Fahrenheit: 179.6
Grados Centigrados: 83 Grados Fahrenheit: 181.4
Grados Centigrados: 84 Grados Fahrenheit: 183.20000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 85 Grados Fahrenheit: 185.0
Grados Centigrados: 86 Grados Fahrenheit: 186.8
Grados Centigrados: 87 Grados Fahrenheit: 188.6
Grados Centigrados: 88 Grados Fahrenheit: 190.4
Grados Centigrados: 89 Grados Fahrenheit: 192.20000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 90 Grados Fahrenheit: 194.0
Grados Centigrados: 91 Grados Fahrenheit: 195.8
Grados Centigrados: 92 Grados Fahrenheit: 197.6
Grados Centigrados: 93 Grados Fahrenheit: 199.4
Grados Centigrados: 94 Grados Fahrenheit: 201.20000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 95 Grados Fahrenheit: 203.0
Grados Centigrados: 96 Grados Fahrenheit: 204.8
Grados Centigrados: 97 Grados Fahrenheit: 206.6
Grados Centigrados: 98 Grados Fahrenheit: 208.4
Grados Centigrados: 99 Grados Fahrenheit: 210.20000000000002
Grados Centigrados: 100 Grados Fahrenheit: 212.0
```

Comment: // Conversion al reves //conversion = (i-32)/1.8;